# Android cannot instantiate Multidex Application

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am getting the following error when I install my app on any device.Kindly provide me a solution.I have never encountered this type of error before.Below I have posted build,gradle,manifest etc..

**Error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jobinsabu.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jobinsabu.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:590)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4964)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1555)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jobinsabu.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jobinsabu.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:986)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:585)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4964) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1555) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jobinsabu.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="---------"/>
        <activity android:name=".others.Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.darsh.multipleimageselect.activities.AlbumSelectActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MultipleImageSelectTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.sa90.materialarcmenu:library:1.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**myapp.java:**

```
public class OhxeeApp extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("App","Started");

    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: change as @alex said in his answer, also if you override `MultiDexApllication` you don't need to do this `MultiDex.install(this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ClassNotFoundException is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM) tries to load a particular class and the specified class cannot
>   be found in the classpath

**Don't**

```
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
 public class OhxeeApp extends MultiDexApplication {
```

**Do**

```
android:name="com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee.others.OhxeeApp"
public class OhxeeApp extends Application {
```

Comment: Unable to instantiate application com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee.others.OhxeeApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee.others.OhxeeApp" on path: /data/app/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee-1.apk

Comment: @jobin make sure your `OhxeeApp` location

Comment: @jobin do `public class OhxeeApp extends Application {`

Answer (score 2):

in your manifest.

```
android:name=".OhxeeApp"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: because qeustion has wrong application attribute(android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication")

Comment: so my answer is fix that

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest change the application name to OhxeeApp:

```
android:name=".OhxeeApp"
```